# Session replication in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, load-balancing, cluster, replication, session

I have setup my cluster with one loadbalancer and 2 nodes with sticky session. I am using mod_jk for loadbalancing. I am having problem with proper session replication. I am using Tomcat 6. When I start a new session I can see that the session is replicated on both the nodes. Thats all good

Content of session

```
Node 1
printstring=["1"]
Node 2
printstring=["1"]
```

But the problem arises when I modify the session object, the updated session is not replicated. Some how the tomcat just doesnt update the session content.

Content of sesion

```
Node 1
printstring=["1","2"]
Node2
printstring=["1"]
```

I am using delta manager for now. I did some research but didnt find anything to help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I bit more of research led to this and I implemented the ForceReplicationValve and it worked like a charm.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680958/is-there-a-usedirtyflag-option-for-tomcat-6-cluster-configuration